Why is the PAM configuration not working properly?
I attempted to edit the /etc/pam.d/su file to achieve the following:

When the current user is userX and executes su userM, no password is required. I used the following configuration:
auth [success=ignore default=1] pam_succeed_if.so user = userM  
auth sufficient pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user = userX  


When the current user is userY and executes su userN, no password is required. I used the following configuration:
auth [success=ignore default=1] pam_succeed_if.so user = userN  
auth sufficient pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user = userY  



The strange issue is that if I configure only userX --> userM or only userY --> userN, both work as expected.
However, when I configure both sections simultaneously, only the latter configuration (userY --> userN) works. When trying su with userX, I get the following error:
su: failed to user credentials: The return value should be ignored by PAM dispatch  

Did I make a mistake in the configuration somewhere?

What does your full configuration look like? Do you have any modules left that would set a "successful" result?

my answer to the title specifically - because getting PAM syntax and logic correct is usually easier said than done.  Make sure to have a backup of the original PAM file to revert to.
